# Get all Bugs in Jira via Rest API

Tags: rest, jira

I am able to get all the issues in Jira via the REST API but how to get only bugs via REST? Bug is one of the issuetype configured in my Jira project.

Answer (score 1):

To get all issue from a certain type (Bug in your case) you can use:

```
yourjira.url/rest/api/2/search?jql=issueType="Bug"
```

Here is a link with more information on the use of JQL queries:
https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues

Comment: Thank you . But this would give the list of all bugs in my Jira instance. I wanna fetch all the bugs in a specific project. Also something wrong with the developer forum. The page is not opening

Comment: If you want them for a specific project try this: yourjira.url/rest/api/2/search?jql=project %3D "ProjectName" AND issuetype %3D Bug

Comment: Thanks Runnigriot!

Comment: No problem, could you please upvote my answer if it solved your problem?